# looping through two directories using batch script

Tags: windows, batch-file, if-statement, for-loop, command-prompt

I want to loop though two directories A and B and where files with same names exist. And once I get path to both of the same name files I want to do some operation. Here is my batch script :

```
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION 
for /r "A" %%o in (*.c,*.cpp,*.h) do (
for /r "B" %%l in (*.c,*.cpp,*.h) do (      
            set x = %%~nxo
            set y = %%~nxl
            if %x% == %y% ( echo %x% )
    )
)
endlocal
```

Here I am trying to print the names of the files but unable to do so. 
I am getting an error : echo was unexpected at this time.
So what is the problem with this script.

Comment: Excuse me. If you know that the files exists in both directories, why a simple listing of any directory isn't enough? It is possible that there are some files that does not exist in one (just one) directory? Or in both? This detail may lead to a much faster solution...

Answer (score 2):

The problem is spaces. Try this code

```
set x=something_1
set x = something_2

echo %x%
echo %x %
```

As you can see, placing a space after the name of the variable alters the name of the variable. You are assigning value to a variable with a space in its name, but try to retrieve the value from a variable without a space in its name.

Once spaces are solved, next problem: delayed expansion.

When execution reachs a block of code (in this case your two `for` commands, the content enclosed in the parenthesis) and **before** the code gets executed, the content is parsed and in all places where variables are readed, **variable references gets replaced with the value of variables**.

The values they have **before** starting the execution of the block.

And then the block is executed the needed times (as stated in the `for` command) **without new substitutions**, as now, there are no reads to variables in the code.

The value of the variables is changed (when the corresponding `set` command is executed), but this changes are no reflected in the code executed. It contains no variables, they were replaced with their values.

The exception to this behaviour are the variables/replaceable parameters of the `for` commands (`%%o` and `%%l` in your code) which are intended to change its value and, when delayed expansion is enabled (`setlocal enabledelayedexpansion`) variables referenced as `!var!` instead of the usual `%var%`

With this in mind, your code executes as it were written as

```
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION 
for /r "A" %%o in (*.c,*.cpp,*.h) do (
for /r "B" %%l in (*.c,*.cpp,*.h) do (      
            set x=%%~nxo
            set y=%%~nxl
            if == ( echo )
    )
)
endlocal
```

There are no reads of the value of the variables. All has been changed with their initial values (in this sample, a emtpy value is assumed)

How to solve: two options

1 - No delayed expansion: use the variables of the for commands

```
for /r "A" %%o in (*.c,*.cpp,*.h) do for /r "B" %%l in (*.c,*.cpp,*.h) do (      
    if "%%~nxo"=="%%~nxl" ( echo "%%~nxo" )
)
```

2 - Delayed expansion enabled

```
for /r "A" %%o in (*.c,*.cpp,*.h) do for /r "B" %%l in (*.c,*.cpp,*.h) do (
    set "x=%%~nxo"
    set "y=%%~nxl"
    if "!x!"=="!y!" ( echo "!x!" )
)
```

Comment: removed spaces from lines 4 and 5. But still problem persists.

Comment: @PiyushGoyal: Please, see updated answer. You corrected one problem, one more and will be solved.

Answer (score 0):

See what this provides for you:

```
@echo off
for /r "A" %%o in (*.c,*.cpp,*.h) do (
for /r "B" %%l in (*.c,*.cpp,*.h) do (      
   if "%%~nxo"=="%%~nxl" echo."%%~nxo"
    )
)
```